Inside and up to boundary regularity improvement of linear differential operator
I'm learning elliptic PDEs and a natural question came to me. Consider a constant coefficient linear differential operator defined on the ball $B_r:=\{\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^2<r\}$
$$A=\sum a_\alpha\partial^\alpha$$
where

$\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a multiindex such that $\partial^\alpha$ is defined to be $\partial_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial_n^{\alpha_n}$
$a_\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ are constants with depending only on the multiindex $\alpha$.

My questions

if $f\in C^{\infty}(B_1)$ satisfies
$$
A f=0\;\text{ in } B_1,
$$
when $f$ is analytic in $B_{1/2}$?
I know that if $A$ is $\Delta$ then the result is true, as it happens also if $A=\Delta+1$. The regularity can even apply to distribution solutions. Is the same result true also for other operators? When can we say that a distributional solution is indeed an analytic function?
Similarly, if for a $C^2$ domain $\Omega$ we have
$$
A f=0\;\text{ in } \Omega,
$$
$$
f=g\;\text{ on } \partial\Omega,
$$
where $g$ is a $C^2$ function. When can we have the $f$ is $C^2$ up to the boundary $\partial\Omega$? Again I know that if $A$ is $\Delta$ then the result is true, as it happens also if $A=\Delta+1$, and again the regularity result holds also for distribution solutions. Is the same result true also for other operators? When can we say that a distributional solution is a $C^2$ function up to the boundary?


About (2) I can think of many harmonic functions in the ball which are not $C^2$ up to the boundary. When you say that this is true for the Laplacian what do you mean ?

@an_ordinary_mathematician Oh thanks for pointing out that. I've reformed the question. BasicallyI mean that if you have a harmonic function such that it is equal to a $C^k$ function on the  boundary together with the condition that the boundary is smooth enough, then the function must be as smooth as the worst condition, here it is  $C^k$.
